# Exception during GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT to group managed service account

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, service-accounts

Did somebody happen to make a `GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::` operation to a group managed service account work? Personally, I can't.

I am always facing the so-called self-explaining exception:

`Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the login 'DOMAIN\GMSA-ACCOUNT', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

the login I use to issue this command is sysadmin-role, so permission shall not be a problem
the `DOMAIN\GMSA-ACCOUNT` account is actually starting the SQL Server engine service, so I guess its existence has been at least validated
As a consequence, I can't make my service broker communication work with gMSA account like it previously was, with a regular service account.

Does somebody have an answer/tip?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Edit

Happens that I have mistakenly been asking this question on StackOverflow.

Answer from [David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) to the original thread was:

> Try again after a while, and try granting to a security group
> containing the GMSA

Thanks David, I must check this workaround.

Comment: Same exception using the security group that is actually containing the computer where the command is executed  For what it's worth, SQL Server box is an Azure IaaS resource.

Comment: Not just any security group containing the account, but the security group which allows the account to connect. The fact that the GMSA account is starting the service is irrelevant, it still doesn't have permission to even connect to the service unless you create a login for it or its parent group. If there is no such group then the whole thing is a moot point: there is no login for this account or any of its groups. Then you would need `CREATE LOGIN DOMAIN\GROUPNAME FROM WINDOWS`

Comment: @Charlieface maybe I don't get things right. AFAIU, group managed account is not really  part of security group but is more related to a security group, which hosts couple of machines that are granted to serve authentication requests for this specific account. Actually, this is how line are currently built. Am I wrong?

Comment: gMSA accounts are just domain accounts (except that the system manages the password, and they have special security permissions). They are used by services to login to machines. They are not necessarily part of any security group other than their main one, and therefore would not have rights to login to SQL Server. Normally what you would do is create an AD group called `Allowed SQL Server` or similar, and add any accounts (including gMSA) to that group. Then you create a SQL Server login for that group, so all accounts now have access. Without a SQL Server login they have no access by default